# Reporte php y Mysql con registros de un mismo cliente

Tags: mysql

Buenas noches espero y me puedan ayudar tengo una consulta en mysql que me despliega los datos de la siguiente manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero necesito que los registros esten de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

estoy haciendo el reporte con fpdf 
llevo lo siguiente

```
$sql1 ="select a.estudiante_Carnet, b.PrimerNombre, b.PrimerApellido, a.Nota1
from notas a
inner join estudiante b
on a.estudiante_Carnet = b.Carnet
where b.grado_CodigoGrado='b3b'";

$res = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$bandera = $row['b.Carnet'];


$pdf = new PDF();
//$pdf = new FPDF('P','mm',array(165,220));

$pdf->Addpage();
$pdf->AliasNbPages();


$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',5);
    $pdf->Ln(10);

   $res2 = mysqli_query($conexion,$sql1);




    $pdf->Cell(10,10, "hola",1,1,'C',0);


while ($fila = $res2->fetch_array())  
{   

    if ( $bandera ==  $fila['b.Carnet'] ) {





    $bandera = $fila['b.Carnet'];

$pdf->Cell(10,10, $fila['PrimerNombre'],1,0,'C',0);         
   $pdf->Cell(10,10, $fila['Nota1'],1,0,'C',0);   
      $pdf->Ln();

  } 

  else { 

     ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////   
    $pdf->Addpage();  


    $bandera = $fila['b.Carnet'];
      $pdf->Cell(10,10, $fila['PrimerNombre'],1,0,'C',0);  
   $pdf->Cell(10,10, $fila['Nota1'],1,0,'C',0);   
      $pdf->Ln();


}   
}

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

Comment: saludos a la espera de otras aportaciones, a mi se me ocurre de este modo, analiza y adapta la siguiente query y checa si te sirve solo es un ejemplo corto a tu ejercicio

Comment: te dejo este ejercicio espero te sirva https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=9ae4db18a7a0903f8716d7cd642dbb10

Comment: @Alfredo eso no sirve, el no sabe los valores de la tabla por lo que los CASE no van a funcionar.

Comment: Lo que necesitas es una cosa llamada `PIVOT`. Por desgracia MySQL no proporciona esta función y vas a tener que programarla tu directamente.

Comment: Por si te sirve, para printrarlo como quieres con la query que ya tienes sólo necesitas seguir añadiendo celdas con el valor de Nota1 mientras el valor de estudiante_Carnet no cambie. Cuando el valor de estudiante_Carnet cambie creas una nueva fila. El diseño inicial de la tabla no es óptimo, en lo que muestras hay demasiados campos repetidos en las tuplas.

Comment: @JDev fue una solución que se me ocurrió y por lo que vez en el enlace si sirve

Comment: @Alfredo el metodo no funciona porque las notas siempre varian. Gracias por enseñar otro metodo

Answer (score 0):

Esta forma de agrupar o estructurar la información es llamada `Pivot`hay bases de datos como SQLServer por ejemplo que traen la funcion incorparada por defecto sin embargo otras como MySQL disponen de solo la practica y la costumbre de hacerlo, se les denomina a estas tablas como `Tabla Pivot`.
Es decir hay que hacer 'chapuzas' u otros ajustes para conseguir el resultado.
Por experiencia propia te recomendaría que trates la información en tu lenguaje de programación directamente para estructurarlo de esta forma ya que lo realizara de forma mas rápida con grandes cantidades de datos.

El efecto es el siguiente:

- Búsqueda normal: 
  [image: Busqueda simple]
- Búsqueda con estructura pivot: 
  [image: Query Pivot] [image: Resultado Pivot]

> No tengo muy claro como están estructuradas tus tablas, pero para conseguir el resultado que necesitas la cantidad de notas tiene que ser fija, es decir; no es posible generar columnas infinitas de notas `Nota1,Nota2...hasta el infinito` en este formato al menos, edita tu respuesta y añade la estructura de las tablas y si es posible cual sera la cantidad máxima de notas por alumno. Y si encima todos en la tabla tiene una Nota1, Nota2 etc mucho mejor.
>   Mi recomendación seria que en la tabla de ´notas´ añadas una columna con el numero de nota, es decir `notas(id,id_alumno,numero_nota,nota):`